# SPLongRunning in page_load without redirect

Tags: development, splongoperation

Is there a way for `SPLongOperation` not to reload the page but only to hide the processing-Wheel? My scenario is that when I open a **model-dialog** I want to show a loading/processing information to the user.

My Example Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (SPLongOperation lo = new SPLongOperation(Page)) 
   {
      lo.Begin();
      // Load controls and stuff
      lo.End(????);
   }
}
```

When i just remove the `lo.End()` call, my new custom controls are shown below the processing-wheel.
When i call `lo.EndScript(string.Empty)` instead of `lo.End()` the controls aren't visible and the processing-wheel won't go away.

Has anyone an idea how to accomplish something like that?